# Debug a .dll file within powershell

Tags: debugging, dll

I have given a .ps1 file which loads a .dll via:

```
Import-Module ".\decrypter.dll"
```

After that, a call to that module is performed by:

```
get-decrypt(" *Some Base64 Encoded string* ")
```

Only the .dll is given. The Dependency Walker returns no exported functions. IDA Pro Free shows only one module
My question:
How do I debug this .dll file?

Kindly regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file `decrypter.dll` is a .NET dll which (if it's not obfuscated) means you can decompile it to full readable source code with tools like [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/), [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) or [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx).

Here are a couple of links from my blog detailing how to use such tools:

- [Modifying a .NET Application](https://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2017/03/14/modifying-net-application/)
- [Redirect Registry by Modifying .NET Executable](https://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2013/05/30/redirect-registry-by-modifying-net-executable/)

Once you have the source code (easiest is to save the decompilation as Visual Studio Project) you can debug the dll code in Visual Studio when calling into the dll from PowerShell.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by the answer before me decrypter.dll is a .NET dll, If you want you can debug it by writing a simple .NET program that references it and calls the same function/method you need, get-decrypt in your case, a nice tool to use for debugging of such a .NET program that can step into its dependency dlls is dnSpy which can be found and downloaded [here](https://github.com/dnSpy/dnSpy/releases).